# import facebook albums into app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I want to import pictures from Facebook directly into my iPhone application to get the links out of it.

- Is there really no way to filter on the type?
- Can I make assumptions about "where" (page wise) the profile pictures album will be?

Currently we are retrieving all (max 300) albums and looking at them after retrieval, but it takes too much time, hence the questions. We need to optimize this part.

For what it's worth, it's a Rails 3 app with Koala handling Facebook interactions

Comment: see my answer..to get photos from facebook using graph api 2.5 ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Answer (score 0):

First you get Facebook access token

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=%@",fbGraph.accessToken
```

and pass Album Id

```
https://graph.facebook.com/%@/photos?type=album&access_token=%@",Albumid,fbGraph.accessToken
```

Comment: Please be careful how you include URLs in your posts. The way you had these, people thought you were trying to link to websites, rather than showing examples of service links. I've formatted them as code, since that's really what you meant them as.